# android java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, out-of-memory

when i download large data from website, i got this error information:

```
I/global  (20094): Default buffer size used in BufferedInputStream constructor.
It would be better to be explicit if an 8k buffer is required.
D/dalvikvm(20094): GC freed 6153 objects / 3650840 bytes in 335ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(20094): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 3599051-byte al
location
D/dalvikvm(20094): GC freed 320 objects / 11400 bytes in 144ms
E/dalvikvm-heap(20094): Out of memory on a 3599051-byte allocation.
I/dalvikvm(20094): "Thread-9" prio=5 tid=17 RUNNABLE
I/dalvikvm(20094):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=0 obj=0x439b9480
I/dalvikvm(20094):   | sysTid=25762 nice=0 sched=0/0 handle=4065496
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: It runs out of memory, apparently... what exactly do you need help with?

Comment: At least provide the full stacktrace and some context information on how you download the data (see, the error message speaks of a BufferedInputStream)

Answer (score 1):

Individual apps do not have access to all available device memory. If you're downloading a large data set consider writing it to the SD card as you go rather than trying to hold it entirely in memory.

Comment: OutOfMemory exceptions usually don't have to do with disk memory but heap or memory/ram. (see http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html)

Comment: hi, adamp,
 i was wirte to SDCard, but it still OutOfMemory. Could you tell me how to recycle Drawable?

Comment: @Toni: You can often process data in chunks to or from local storage in situations where attempting to load the entire data set into memory at once would result in OOM.

@xiangdream: If your large data are images in the form of Drawables (BitmapDrawables?) take a look at the BitmapFactory decoding methods and the inSampleSize field of BitmapFactory.Options. You can resample an image to a smaller size while loading it to save memory. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html Some more information about what you're trying to do would be helpful. :)