# how to fix error in bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: android, exception, bitmap, size, out-of-memory

i am working one application image uploading to sdcard i am scaling that sdcard saved into database some times one error is occurs bitmap size exceeds vm budget

```
ouput :

01-11 15:39:51.809: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6214): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-11 15:39:51.979: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6214): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
01-11 15:39:51.979: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
01-11 15:39:51.979: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:384)
01-11 15:39:51.979: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:397)
01-11 15:39:51.979: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at com.fitzgeraldsoftware.shout.presentationLayer.Shout.onActivityResult(Shout.java:1653)
01-11 15:39:51.979: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3624)
01-11 15:39:51.979: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3220)
01-11 15:39:51.979: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3266)
01-11 15:39:51.979: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2600(ActivityThread.java:116)
01-11 15:39:51.979: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1823)
01-11 15:39:51.979: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-11 15:39:51.979: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-11 15:39:51.979: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
01-11 15:39:51.979: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 15:39:51.979: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-11 15:39:51.979: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
01-11 15:39:51.979: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
01-11 15:39:51.979: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6214):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

how can fix the error please forward some solution thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

narasimha , I suppose may be this post will help you

[android-strange-out-of-memory-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue)

or this 
[java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949066/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android)

or may be this
[android-java-lang-outofmemoryerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938164/android-java-lang-outofmemoryerror)

& there are more questions already there

Answer (score 1):

You have a memory leak. You need to investigate to find it. This could be unreleased Bitmap or Cursor ...

[Inspect the heap](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html) to see what kind of objects you have.

Comment: Make sure you cache them or you call `.release()`